# Use Apache Common Digester to Parse XML

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-digester

I have a xml:

```
<element name="PersonalNote" enabled="true" >
```

and the digester xml:

```
<set-properties-rule>
          <alias attr-name="name" prop-name="name" />
          <alias attr-name="enabled" prop-name="enabled" />          
</set-properties-rule>
```

Now I want to add some new attributes:

```
<element name="PersonalNote" enabled="true" mandatory=”true” minLength=”0” maxLengh=”100”>
```

Perhaps there are more attributes need to be added in the future, so how to implement this without modifying the digester xml, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to just remove the `<alias>` elements.

By default `<set-properties-rule>` will map all attributes to the equivalent bean properties. You only need aliases if your bean properties don't match your XML attributes.

Remove the `<alias>` elements entirely, and keep your XML and JavaBean in-sync, and everything should work fine.